# Do i need to verify iPhone in app purchase receipt?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have implemented an in-app purchase into my iPhone application. It is non-consumable, and it basically flags a BOOLEAN that allows the user to access an additional viewcontroller. Works great. But in apple's documentation, there is alot of stuff about verifying the receipt. Is this necessary? I don't use an external server for my purchase.

Even if it is not necessary, can I just save the receipt to NSUserDefaults?

Comment: You can use ReceiptKit https://github.com/maciekish/ReceiptKit for easy verification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can trust the Apple Server.
Long answer: there're some software for jb iphones that let users to obtain "fake" purchase receipts, so if you don't verify the receipt your sw can be fooled...
That said depends on your situation: having a server to check/validate receipts can cost you more that letting some thiefs to stole your work. But again weight your options...

Comment: and we also basically write the same things! are you my separated from the birth identical twin? :D  (sorry for the spam moderatos...)

Comment: So i should just tell my iPhone app to directly send a JSON to https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt?

Answer (score 2):

You should verify the recipe, because otherwise there will be users with a jailbreak and a tool that just pretends to be an Apple server and says yes to every in app purchase. If you verify the recipe with the Apple server, you can guarantee that the user really bought the content.